# How to run a function AFTER the page load on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hook, action

I have this code which i use to fetch json data from an api:

```
    $imdbid = $_GET['ids'];
    $string = file_get_contents("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=".$imdbid."&apikey=9a187152");
    $json = json_decode($string, true);


    echo json_encode(array
        (           
            'imdbid' => $json['imdbID'],
            'title' => $json['Title'],
            'synopsis' => $json['Plot'],
            'genre' => $json['Genre'],
            'response' => 'success'
        ));

    myFunction($imdbid, $json);
```

It can echo all the data fetched from `$string` **but my problem is that the page is white/blank until** `myFunction($imdbid, $json)` **finished its course.**

**Is there any action/hook** i can use so that the data i fetched is **echoed/displayed immediately** on the frontend then `myFunction($imdbid, $json)` **only starts/called after the page** load so that my page is not blank?

Answer (score 0):

You can [enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) the script in the head rather than the footer but I think you'd have to get and process the data via PHP rather than javascript if you want it to be there on page load.